# Cisco switch traffic logs?

Tags: cisco, network-traffic

first i don't know anything about cisco, im doing my own research on side but i think it will be faster if i ask here at the same time.

I want to monitor the traffic from a cisco switch per interfaces and per ip.
I already did that for a zyxel siwtch, who use traffic logs to send data on a remote server, with for fomat something like that :

Jun 27 12:15:08 2016 usg60 src="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56121" dst="8.8.8.8:53" msg="Traffic Log" note="Traffic Log" user="unknown" devID="xxxxxxxxxxx" cat="Traffic Log" duration=104 sent=258 rcvd=258 dir="lan1:wan1" protoID=17 proto="domain" client_mac="xxxxxx"

I am parsing it and then proced to monitor the data as i want.

I want to know if something similar is possible for cisco switch, like that i can use my rsyslog server and kept the script i actualy use.

If not, then how could i get the traffic from a switch on a remote server to use my monitoring tool (wich is zabbix).

I will prefer not to use tool i need to install on switch, like sflow or similar stuff.

Thank you for reading and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily collect data about port utilization and more from switch by SNMP in Zabbix. But collecting information about conversations is difficult on Cisco switches, usually Cisco not write this information in logs, but you could try to enable NetFlow on switch(if it possible to use) and collect required data on your server.

BTW, what Cisco switch you have?